# Hibernate duplicate entry

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, servlets, nhibernate-mapping

I have Registration table.That has many duplicate entries. Here duplicate entries in terms of same username. so I want to know how to prevent the duplicate entries in a table. I am using Hibernate and java servlet.

Comment: make the username column unique in your schema. There is nothing to do with hibernate. And handle the unique name exception in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an unique constraint on the username.

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=
           @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username"})) 
public class Registration {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Column(name = "username",unique=true)
```

at column level.